# change text of slide in java using aspose api ppt

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint, aspose-slides

```
public void save()
{ Presentation pres = new Presentation(filename);

ISlide slide = pres.getSlides().get_Item(0);

IShape shape= null;


for (int i = 0 ; i < slide.getShapes().size() ; i++)
{    shape = slide.getShapes().get_Item(i);
if (shape.getPlaceholder() != null)
{
((IAutoShape)shape).getTextFrame().setText(txtArea.getText());
}
}


pres.save(filename,SaveFormat.Ppt);

}
```

This code is for changing the text but it's not working. I have used two APIs at a time, display code is below:

```
public void Display(int currentPage, String source)
    {
        try {
        // Create a slideshow object; this creates an underlying POIFSFileSystem object for us
        SlideShow ppt = new SlideShow(new HSLFSlideShow(source));
        current=currentPage;
        // Get all of the slides from the PPT file
        Slide[] slides = ppt.getSlides();
        Dimension pgsize = ppt.getPageSize();
        all = slides.length;
        String temp="";
        lblPage.setText(currentPage+" / "+all);

            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(pgsize.width, pgsize.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics();
graphics.setPaint(Color.white);
graphics.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, pgsize.width, pgsize.height));

//render
slides[currentPage-1].draw(graphics);
//save the output
            /*FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("slide-" + (i + 1) + ".png");
            javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(img, "png", out);
            out.close();
            //ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("slide-" + (i + 1) + ".png");*/
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
            lblPresentasi.setIcon(icon);
// Obtain metrics about the slide: its number and name
            int number = slides[currentPage-1].getSlideNumber();
            String title = slides[currentPage-1].getTitle();
            // Obtain the embedded text in the slide
            TextRun[] textRuns = slides[currentPage-1].getTextRuns();
            System.out.println("Slide " + number + ": " + title);
            System.out.println("\tText Runs");
            txtArea.setText("Slide : " + number + " Title : " + title + "\n");
            for (int j = 0; j < textRuns.length; j++) {
                // Display each of the text runs present on the slide
                System.out.println("\t\t" + j + ": " + textRuns[j].getText());
                temp=txtArea.getText();
                txtArea.setText(temp+"\t\t" + textRuns[j].getText() + "\n");
            }

            // Obtain the notes for this slide
            System.out.println("\tNotes: ");
            Notes notes = slides[currentPage-1].getNotesSheet();
            if (notes != null) {
                // Notes are comprised of an array of text runs
                TextRun[] notesTextRuns = notes.getTextRuns();
                for (int j = 0; j < notesTextRuns.length; j++) {
                    System.out.println("\t\t" + notesTextRuns[j].getText());
                }
            }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Can anyone please help, I am trying to make a simple powerpoint editor in Java. 
I want to change text in textarea press save button so text has to change and call display function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have observed your sample code and like to share that as far as code related to Aspose.Slides is concerned, there is no issue and it is perfectly right. You can verify this by opening the saved presentation with changed text in PowerPoint. If you encounter any issue in this, we will be glad to help you further. You may also contact us in [Aspose.Slides support forums](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.slides-product-family/109/showforum.aspx) as well.

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.